# Space of bounded functions vs. bounded space of functions.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, compact-operators

Suppose I have a bounded set of functions, say $B\subset C[0,1]$. What exactly does this mean? I.e. is a bounded set of continuous functions equivalent to a set of continuous bounded functions? For reference, I'm proving an operator $T:X\to Y$ is compact showing that $T(B)\subset Y$ is precompact for every bounded set $B\subset X$.

Comment: First, to say that $B\subset C[0,1]$ is bounded, you need a norm $|| \cdot ||$ on $C[0,1]$. Then this means that there exists a real number $M$ such that for all $f\in B$, $|| f || < M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a bounded set of continuous functions is different from a set of bounded continuous functions. In your case of $C[0,1]$, note that every $f \in C[0,1]$ is a bounded continuous function, due to the compactness of $[0,1]$. A subset $B \subseteq C[0,1]$ is a bounded set if there is one bound for all the functions in $B$, that is the number 
$$ \sup_{f \in B} \|f\|_\infty $$
exists (i. e., is finite).

Comment: Good point on the compactness, poor example choice. Regardless though, suppose we have some set $B\subset C(\mathbb{R})$ and we're using the sup-norm. If B is bounded as a set, then $\sup_{f\in B} \|f\|_\infty = \sup_{f\in B} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|$, correct? And if this is finite, then all $f\in B$ are bounded functions. Conversely, if $f$ is bounded for all $f\in B$, then $\sup_{f\in B} \|f\|_\infty$ should exist and be finite right, thus implying $B$ is bounded?

Comment: @BenSouthworth If $\sup_{f \in B} \sup_{x\in \mathbb R} |f(x)|$ is bounded, all $f \in B$ are bounded functions. But on the other hand, all $f$ being bounded does not suffice! Let $B = \{f_n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$, where $f_n \colon x \mapsto n$ is the constant-value-$n$-function. Then each $f_n$ is bounded, but $B$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your question a set $B$ is bounded means that it is a collection of vectors that are all bounded in norm by some value $M$.

However the norm you are probably using on $C[0,1]$ is $\| x \| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |x(t)|$.  This should show you the connection between your two phrases.